# Built in core image-filter colorCube/colorCubeWithColorSpace leads to strange result sometimes

Tags: swift, core-image

I have made a LUT which I apply to an image via colorCubeWithColorSpace() (I have also tried colorCube()). Sometimes it leads to some kind of clipping/artefacts in the dark areas, it always turns green instead of black which is what happen if I use the LUT in an video editing software like FCP X or Davinci Resolve. This only happens where the image is dark, and not always, so it seems a bit random, even if it's repeatable with the same images. Anyone know if it has something to do with colour spaces, or are there some parameters I can use with the colorCube-filter to clamp it to black instead some weird green? I'll include a sample of a source image and the resulting image so you can see what I mean.[image]

This is the code where I apply the filter:

```
let filter = CIFilter.colorCubeWithColorSpace()
filter.inputImage = ciImage
filter.cubeData = colorCube
filter.cubeDimension = 33
filter.colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
outputImage = filter.outputImage
```